# Would Server Sent Events forcing Netty to hold same thread until the stream is closed?

Tags: multithreading, netty, spring-webflux, server-sent-events, reactor-netty

Context: HTML5 frontend will call a service answering a Flux. The purpose to use Spring WebFlux with Netty is taking advantage of less threads demanded and pushing events one-way from Server to Fronted. By events I mean numerous status changing until the end. The stack is full reactive: Angular9/RxJS -> Spring WebFlux/Netty -> springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository -> MongoDb. As far as I can see this is really a non-blocking stack (see snippets code bellow that I am confident I am not blocking anywhere). Additionaly you can see that SSE is really enable: produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE on Rest Service and EventSource on Front.

Main question: since from the first status to the last status may take from 10 seconds to 30 seconds, will the thread be hold during this time? I consider long time taking in account we have Sensedia Api Gateway. If so, I would start wonder if there is some gain to use no -blocking server (eg. Netty) over blocing ones (eg. Tomcat). Disclames: I am only talking about avoid Threads creation and locks in my specific scenario. I am not comparing servers in general.

Microservice Boot:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;

@EnableWebFlux
@SpringBootApplication
public class FluxdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FluxdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

SSE Controller Endpoint:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.reactive.fluxdemo.domain.Transfer;
import com.reactive.fluxdemo.repository.TransferRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
public class TransferController {

    // Server Sent Events
    @GetMapping(value = "/stream/transfers", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Transfer> streamAllTransfers() {
        return transferRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Domain:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Transfer {
    @Id
    private String id;
...
    private Integer status;
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.reactive.fluxdemo.domain.*;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;

@Repository
public interface TransferRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Transfer, String> {

}
```

FrontEnd
Either one of bellow is HTML5 SSE. For this question it doesn't matter pure HTML5 or a more complex Observer. BTW, I pasted bellow both to exemplify that Front opens a Server Sent Events channel.

Simplified Version with pure HTML5

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    var source = new EventSource();
    source.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log('New message is received');
        const index = JSON.parse(e.data);
        const content = `New event added: ${index.status}<br>`;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += content;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Complete Version with Angular/RxJs Observer

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Extrato } from './extrato';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SseService {
  extratos: Extrato[] = [];
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { }

  getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {
    this.extratos = [];
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
          this.extratos.push(new Extrato(json['id'], json['description'], json['value'], json['status']));
          observer.next(this.extratos);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }

    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could increase the bounty  or find someway to call attention from some expert on it. This is highly relevant question for anyone moving to SpringFlux/Netty stack and unfortunatelly I couldn't find any answer searching around for days.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this question?! It seems so relevant for anyone interested to use Netty somehow

Comment: I am really looking at this question. Any clue will be highly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure the code does what you think it does. When it reaches the end of the collection the `Flux` will complete (not block and wait for more transfers). Do you have any reason to believe that threads are blocking (you could see it in jvisualvm for instance)?